# Python: How to correctly convert CSV without headers to JSON

Tags: python, arrays, json, csv, sorting

I have to convert a lot of CSV files to JSON files. As you can see below there are no headers.
I have managed to create code for that:

```
import gspread
import os
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload


import csv
import json
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path


#Odczyt pliku CSV
def read_CSV(file, json_file):
    csv_rows = []
    with open(file) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        field = reader.fieldnames
        for row in reader:
            csv_rows.extend([{field[i]:row[field[i]] for i in range(len(field))}])
        convert_write_json(csv_rows, json_file) #definicja funkcji ponizej

#Zamiana CSV na JSON
def convert_write_json(data, json_file):
    with open(json_file, "w") as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(data, sort_keys=False, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))) 
        f.write(json.dumps(data))

#pętla w folderze
pliki = "/users/user/CSVtoGD/"

files = Path(pliki).glob('*.csv') 

for f in files:
    read_CSV(f, str(f.with_suffix('.json')))
```

CSVs look like the example:

```
Assets/Lakeside/Resources/Graphics/font_ttf/Roboto-Bold_0.ttf,Roboto,Bold,Roboto Bold,Roboto-Bold,Version 2.137; 2017,Roboto Bold,Google,Christian Robertson,Google.com,Roboto is a trademark of Google.,Copyright 2011 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.,http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0,,GOOG
Assets/Lakeside/Resources/Graphics/font_ttf/Roboto-Medium_0.ttf,Roboto Medium,Regular,Roboto Medium,Roboto-Medium,Roboto,,Version 2.137; 2017,Roboto Medium,Google,Christian Robertson,Google.com,Roboto is a trademark of Google.,Copyright 2011 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.,http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0,,GOOG
(...)
```

But the results are not quite spectacular:

```
[
    {
        "Assets/Lakeside/Resources/Graphics/font_ttf/Roboto-Bold_0.ttf": "Assets/Lakeside/Resources/Graphics/font_ttf/Roboto-Medium_0.ttf",
        "Roboto": "Roboto Medium",
        "Bold": "Regular",
        "Roboto Bold": "",
        "Roboto-Bold": "Roboto-Medium",
        "Version 2.137; 2017": "Roboto",
        "Google": "Version 2.137; 2017",
        "Christian Robertson": "Roboto Medium",
        "Google.com": "Google",
        "Roboto is a trademark of Google.": "Christian Robertson",
        "Copyright 2011 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.": "Google.com",
        "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0": "Roboto is a trademark of Google.",
        "": "Copyright 2011 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.",
        "GOOG": "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0"
    }
][{"Assets/Lakeside/Resources/Graphics/font_ttf/Roboto-Bold_0.ttf": "Assets/Lakeside/Resources/Graphics/font_ttf/Roboto-Medium_0.ttf", "Roboto": "Roboto Medium", "Bold": "Regular", "Roboto Bold": "", "Roboto-Bold": "Roboto-Medium", "Version 2.137; 2017": "Roboto", "Google": "Version 2.137; 2017", "Christian Robertson": "Roboto Medium", "Google.com": "Google", "Roboto is a trademark of Google.": "Christian Robertson", "Copyright 2011 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.": "Google.com", "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0": "Roboto is a trademark of Google.", "": "Copyright 2011 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.", "GOOG": "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0"}]
```

I have no idea how to sort the information in the JSON files. As you can see, CSVs are just data for one TTF in every row. (ex. Family, Vendor etc.)

EDIT: The results I want to have is something lik that:

```
[
    {
        "Assets/HighroadEngine/MMTools/Achievements/Fonts/orange kid.ttf:Family": "Orange Kid",
        "Assets/HighroadEngine/MMTools/Achievements/Fonts/orange kid.ttf:Subfamily": "Regular",
        "Assets/HighroadEngine/MMTools/Achievements/Fonts/orange kid.ttf:Full name": "OrangeKid-Regular",
        "Assets/HighroadEngine/MMTools/Achievements/Fonts/orange kid.ttf:PostScript name": "OrangeKid-Regular",
        "Assets/HighroadEngine/MMTools/Achievements/Fonts/orange kid.ttf:Preferred family": "Orange Kid",
        "Assets/HighroadEngine/MMTools/Achievements/Fonts/orange kid.ttf:Preferred subfamily": "Regular",
        "Assets/HighroadEngine/MMTools/Achievements/Fonts/orange kid.ttf:Mac font menu name": "OrangeKid-Regular",
        "Assets/HighroadEngine/MMTools/Achievements/Fonts/orange kid.ttf:Version": "OTF 4.000;PS 001.001;Core 1.0.29",
        "Assets/HighroadEngine/MMTools/Achievements/Fonts/orange kid.ttf:Unique ID": ""
    }
]
[
    {
        "nextfont.ttf:Family": "Orange Kid",
        "nextfont:Subfamily": "Regular",
        "nextfont.ttf:Full name": "OrangeKid-Regular",
        "nextfont.ttf:PostScript name": "OrangeKid-Regular",
        (...)
    }
]
```

Comment: what result do you expect? maybe you should convert it on your own without using module `json`

Comment: if you don't have headers then maybe you should read it as normal `csv`, not `DictReader`, and use own list with headers - `["Family", "Vendor", ...]`, and `zip(fields, headers)`. OR simply first read all as string using standard `open()` `read()`, add headers at the beginning of this string and later run it with `csv`. I think it can load data from string - or you can use `io.StringIO` to create file-like object in memory.

Comment: @furas well I want to properly sort this information but I have no idea how to achieve that. All code that I was trying is creating pretty nice JSON (the first part of my results) but also it copies all the information again in the end of the file. Also the information is mixed in rows. ex "Bold: Regular" - those are two different informations and it should not be in the same row.

Comment: I have no idea how to achieve those things that you talk about. I will try to find some info tho :) thank you

Comment: maybe use `field = ["Family", "Vendor", "Other", ...]` instead of `field = reader.fieldnames` (PL: powodzenia :) )

Comment: what result do you expect? Show it in question.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what result you expect but you could simply add own list with headers

```
fields = ["Family", "Vendor", "Other1", "Other2", "Other3", ...]
```

instead of

```
field = reader.fieldnames
```

---

Minimal working code.

I used `io` only create file in memory so everyone can simply copy and thest it but you should use `open()`

I found only one problem. Your example rows have some values in different columns - ie. version.

```
data = '''Assets/Lakeside/Resources/Graphics/font_ttf/Roboto-Bold_0.ttf,Roboto,Bold,Roboto Bold,Roboto-Bold,Version 2.137; 2017,Roboto Bold,Google,Christian Robertson,Google.com,Roboto is a trademark of Google.,Copyright 2011 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.,http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0,,GOOG
Assets/Lakeside/Resources/Graphics/font_ttf/Roboto-Medium_0.ttf,Roboto Medium,Regular,Roboto Medium,Roboto-Medium,Version 2.137; 2017,Roboto Medium,Google,Christian Robertson,Google.com,Roboto is a trademark of Google.,Copyright 2011 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.,http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0,,GOOG
'''

import csv
import json
import io

# --- load CVS ---

input_filename  = 'input.csv'
output_filename = 'output.json'

fields = ["Family", "Vendor", "Other1", "Other2", "Other3", "Other4", "Other5", "Other6", "Other7"]
csv_rows = []

#with open(input_filename) as fh_in:
with io.StringIO(data) as fh_in:
    reader = csv.reader(fh_in)
    for row in reader:
        dictionary = dict(zip(fields, row))
        csv_rows.append(dictionary)

# --- write JSON in file ---

with open(output_filename, "w") as fh_out:
    json.dump(csv_rows, fh_out, indent=4)

# --- display JSON ---

print(json.dumps(csv_rows, indent=4))
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "Family": "Assets/Lakeside/Resources/Graphics/font_ttf/Roboto-Bold_0.ttf",
        "Vendor": "Roboto",
        "Other1": "Bold",
        "Other2": "Roboto Bold",
        "Other3": "Roboto-Bold",
        "Other4": "Version 2.137; 2017",
        "Other5": "Roboto Bold",
        "Other6": "Google",
        "Other7": "Christian Robertson"
    },
    {
        "Family": "Assets/Lakeside/Resources/Graphics/font_ttf/Roboto-Medium_0.ttf",
        "Vendor": "Roboto Medium",
        "Other1": "Regular",
        "Other2": "Roboto Medium",
        "Other3": "Roboto-Medium",
        "Other4": "Version 2.137; 2017",
        "Other5": "Roboto Medium",
        "Other6": "Google",
        "Other7": "Christian Robertson"
    }
]
```